# Express request routes twice on browser page load

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-side

There are already too many questions/threads regarding mysterious double request of routes. Everyone pointed to favicon.ico thing.

But unfortunately not working for me! I tried with app.use(express.favicon());
Now I have added commented the above app.use statement and added `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">` to the main template. Still nothing. Tried [short-circuiting](https://gist.github.com/kentbrew/763822) it, still nothing.

I have a route view counter, which shows a doubled value. And I assume, its also consuming double resources.

```
GET /login 200 65ms - 2.5kb
GET /login 304 66ms
```

This is how it logs in the terminal. How can I stop this?

(I tested it with cURL via command-line, no issues at all)

Comment: If you load /login with chrome developer tools open, can you post the request bodies that get logged to the "network" tab? If it was favicon, you'd actually see /favicon.ico in the URL path. Can you also include your HTML for "/login" because in general that's what browsers do - they parse HTML and based on the tags in there they make additional GET requets.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I solved it. I was continuously checking the network tab and saw same page is being called twice. Bu after you asked me to post it here, I checked it again, properly this time. For the second call, I noticed the initiator as jQuery. Voila! disabled JS and no issues. Checked my custom js and figured out a nacked `$.get($(".user-tweets-link").attr("href"), function(data) {...` call. Wrapped it with a `if($(".user-tweets-link").length > 0)` and its gone :) Thanks again! PS: Is it okay to add this as an 'answer' below? people might do similar stupid thing and get confused.

Comment: Yes, please post and accept your answer. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was confusing as all over the internet this issue is solved by rectifying the favicon thing.

But this was stupid jquery $.get() call which was firing blank (it was calling the same url as the page url) when the variable was not present. I wrapped the ajax call and problem solved.

Comment: how do i avoid that call?